# I can't install Anaconda on a MacBook Pro M1 with Ventura 13.3.1

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, macos-ventura

this is my first question here :)
When i try to install Anaconda on my MacBook (M1) with Ventura 13.3.1 i receive the following error:

"This package is incompatible with this version of macOS."

I tried the arm64 installer and the x86 installer, both lead to the same error message.
I used Anaconda on the same MacBook just a few days ago, but after the update from Ventura 13.2.1 to 13.3 I couldn't open Jupyter Notebooks from within the Anaconda Navigator. First I thought that the problem might be caused by Anaconda, so I uninstalled it. However, now here I am, unable to install it again. I also did a complete reset of my MacBook, nothing changed.

Does anyone have the same issue or know how I can fix this?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have homebrew installed you should be able to run "brew install anaconda"

Comment: Thank you very much, i just installed homebrew and it worked out perfectly!

For anyone with the same issue, here are the Steps to take inside of homebrew:
https://gist.github.com/ryanorsinger/7d89ad58901b5590ec3e1f23d7b9f887

Comment: Yes, and please make sure that Homebrew downloads the arm64 version: Downloading https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2023.09-0-MacOSX-arm64.sh

I tried the official arm64 version from anaconda website, and it might still have few intel-x86 components that bombed navigator start with the following error:

(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))

Comment: Update: The hombrew installs ok, but running the navigator `anaconda-navigator` still runs into issue - 

`File "/opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/qtpy/QtCore.py", line 15, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/user/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem as you, I installed on my account only instead of Macintosh HD and it worked like a breeze.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 10):

Change the installation folder, so it doesn't install in the System folder.
For example change it to your user folder:

[image: highlights button to Change Installation Folder]

Comment: it works. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting a different partition/folder for the installation.

Answer (score 1):

> If you get the error message “You cannot install Anaconda in this location,” reselect Install for me only.

https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/mac-os/